# I set the stack to be bottomCenter but it doesn't work

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: App Functionality]

Can you help me solve this problem
Where the word beach should be at the bottom of the picture, but it does not go down

Comment: Hi. Please consider adding a link to the code, or the code itself to your question instead of posting a screenshot. It helps others trying out what’s wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use second widget of Stack as Expanded widget instead of Container widget:

```
Expanded(
child: Align(
alignement: FractionalOffset.bottom,
child: Text(.................)
))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can switch the Image and container order in the Stack children's or better option you can use [Positioned()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html) widget to give the container that includes the text a specific position.

Flutter Dev videos:

- https://youtu.be/liEGSeD3Zt8?t=49
- https://youtu.be/EgtPleVwxBQ

[flutter](/questions/tagged/flutter)[dart](/questions/tagged/dart)[postioned](/questions/tagged/postioned)[stack](/questions/tagged/stack)[widget](/questions/tagged/widget)